# How use ADF Parameter Form in Oracle OEPE

Tags: eclipse, oracle-adf

I currently following the tutorial provided at [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse ADF Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/eclipse/adf/gettingStarted/Tutorial/ADFwithOEPE_4.html)

It says

> Drag **`getEmployeesFindBySal`**.......... and select **Parameter > ADF Parameter Form**.

But when I drag drop in Eclipse Neon version I don't see that dialog and there is no `getEmployeesFindBySal` in the data control.

Did anyone worked in latest Eclipse Neon OEPE 12.2.1 and faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Neon OEPE 12.2.1 the UI is bit changed. As per your tutorial the `getEmployeesFindBySal` in data control will be displayed as `employeesFindBySal`.

You need to expand `employeesFindBySal` and locate `Operations`, Inside you will see `ExecuteWithParams`. You need to drag and drop this to your page then the **ADF Parameter Form** will appear.

Comment: your idea is working but the final solution seems not running. It is suppose the provide me a search result, but I end up with errors only. I will try to re-create from scratch